# How to refactor this into generic Expression?

Tags: c#, expression-trees

How can I refactor this C# code into one generic `GetBy(string property, string search)` method?

```
public MyModel GetByName(string name)
    {
        return GetAll().SingleOrDefault(d => string.Equals(d.Name, name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    public MyModel GetByUrl(string url)
    {
        return GetAll().SingleOrDefault(d => string.Equals(d.Url, url, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

`GetAll()` gives back List of MyModel, so this can be an issue also, it is not an `IQueryable` result.

Comment: Be aware that if you do this, you lose all type safety, generally that's a bad idea...

Comment: How about `public MyModel Get(Expression<Func<MyModel, string>> property, value)` so you can ensure callers only pass a valid property? or omit the Expression if you have a list in memory already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could but it's not a good way to maintain type safety.
Alternatively, you could do it like that:

```
public MyModel GetBy<T>(Func<MyModel, T> property, T value) where T : IEquatable<T> {
        return GetAll().SingleOrDefault(d => property(d).Equals(value));
    }

GetBy(m => m.Name, "Foo");
```

Or:

```
    public MyModel GetBy(Func<MyModel, bool> predicate) {
                return GetAll().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
            }

GetBy(m => m.Name.Equals("Foo", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: I would add at the first solution maybe in case typeof(T) == typeof(string) the string comparison parameter...

Comment: I choose the second. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Using Reflection one can late-bind to the desired property:

```
    public MyModel GetBy(string name, string value)
    {
        var getter = typeof(MyModel).GetProperty(name).GetGetMethod();
        return GetAll().SingleOrDefault(d => 
            string.Equals(getter.Invoke(d, null).ToString(), value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
```

(The above assumes the named property always exists and is never null)

Answer (score -1):

You can just call the existing methods

```
public MyModel GetBy(string property, string search)
{
    switch (property) {
        case nameof(MyModel.Name):
            return GetByName(search);
        case nameof(MyModel.Url):
            return GetByUrl(search);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException($"Unsupported property \"{property}\"");
    }
}
```

And of course, you can inline these two functions.

But why call it on `GetAll` instead of `Set<MyModel>`?

Comment: This looks like a bit of a hack, and I *think* OP wants the method to be generic so it could work for any property, though that's a guess.

Comment: I use GetAll because of there are some logic behind GetAll, not just simle DbSet.